# ssh to a server from a machine that is behind proxy

Tags: ssh

I would like to ssh to a server that is public from a local machine that is behind a proxy. So Computer A has address a.b.c.d and Computer B is behind a proxy w.x.y.z:abcd. So how to ssh to Computer A from Computer B?

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by `a proxy`? Are we talking NAT (network address translation)? Do you have an account on the proxy w.x.y.z? What is abcd in this context? If you have an account on the proxy and are using openssh, then you might be looking for the `-J` option .

Comment: Here, proxy means that whenever a request for a certain website is made, it goes to a proxy server that has an IP of w.x.y.z running on port 'abcd', where the server checks whether the website requested should be allowed or not and then the request is made public. It is not the same as NAT though which just translates a private IP to a public IP. So basically I need to bypass the IP of Computer A(in question) before I make an `ssh`. So how should we do that?

Comment: Here you say `website`. This sounds like an http and/or https proxy. Typically these do not support ssh, although they can. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_tunnel  If you can install software on both A and B then you can use http to tunnel IP, e.g. http://http-tunnel.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Computer A is not a website server. It is just a server that holds data and I want to retrieve them but I am not being able to ssh to the server(Connection Time out occurs) because the system from which I am trying to do ssh is behind a proxy

Comment: I didn't say or mean to suggest that A is currently a webserver. However you do need to make it a webserver so B can get the web proxy (w.x.y.z:abcd) to connect to it. You will also need B to run a web client.